# Falta um espaço: "2 hatrás"

Tags: bug, status-pronto, localização

O comportamento se observa na lista de questões depois que a página é atualizada via ajax (uma questão nova surge e você clica na barra amarela):

[image: hatras]

No meio do código minificado do site achei o seguinte:

```
function(a){return 1==a.hours?a.hours+"h atr\u00e1s":a.hours+" hatr\u00e1s"}
                                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Parece que faltou um espaço ali na tradução.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That was a typo in the translation, which is already corrected.

---

Foi um erro de tradução que já está corrigido.